# R: Using for loop on data frame

Tags: r, loops

I have a data frame, `deflator`.

I want to get a new data frame `inflation` which can be calculated by:

```
 deflator[i] - deflator[i-4]
----------------------------- * 100
        deflator [i - 4]
```

The data frame `deflator` has 71 numbers:

```
> deflator
 [1] 0.9628929 0.9596746 0.9747274 0.9832532 0.9851884
 [6] 0.9797770 0.9913502 1.0100561 1.0176906 1.0092516
[11] 1.0185932 1.0241043 1.0197975 1.0174097 1.0297328
[16] 1.0297071 1.0313232 1.0244618 1.0347808 1.0480411
[21] 1.0322142 1.0351968 1.0403264 1.0447121 1.0504402
[26] 1.0487097 1.0664664 1.0935239 1.0965951 1.1141851
[31] 1.1033155 1.1234482 1.1333870 1.1188136 1.1336276
[36] 1.1096461 1.1226584 1.1287245 1.1529588 1.1582911
[41] 1.1691221 1.1782178 1.1946234 1.1963453 1.1939922
[46] 1.2118189 1.2227960 1.2140535 1.2228828 1.2314258
[51] 1.2570788 1.2572214 1.2607763 1.2744415 1.2982076
[56] 1.3318808 1.3394186 1.3525902 1.3352815 1.3492751
[61] 1.3593859 1.3368135 1.3642940 1.3538567 1.3658135
[66] 1.3710932 1.3888638 1.4262185 1.4309707 1.4328823
[71] 1.4497201
```

This is a very tricky question for me. 
I tried to do this using a for loop:

```
> d <- data.frame(deflator)
> for (i in 1:71) {d <-rbind(d,c(delfaotr ))}
```

I think I might be doing it wrong.

Comment: if "loop" function is not the appropriate to it, what should i do?
stuck on this question for hours.. :(

Answer (score 2):

Why use data frames? This is a straightforward vector operation.

```
inflation = 100 * (deflator[1:67] -  deflator[-(1:4)])/deflator[-(1:4)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Fhnuzoag that your example suggests calculations on a numeric vector, not a data frame. Here's an additional way to do your calculations taking advantage of the `lag` argument in the `diff` function (with indexes that match those in your question):

```
lagBy <- 4 # The number of indexes by which to lag

laggedDiff <- diff(deflator, lag = lagBy) # The numerator above

theDenom <- deflator[seq_len(length(deflator) - lagBy)] # The denominator above

inflation <- laggedDiff/theDenom
```

The first few results are:

```
head(inflation)
# [1] 0.02315470 0.02094710 0.01705379 0.02725941 0.03299085 0.03008297
```